# Should I use a GZIP compression middleware or not?

Tags: google-app-engine, wsgi

Having worked with [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), I've seen that people tend to reccommend the use of [GZIP Middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.gzip) to compress HTML pages.

However, the [WSGI v1.0 specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#handling-the-content-length-header) tells us:

> (Note: applications and middleware **must not** apply any kind of `Transfer-Encoding` to their output, such as chunking or gzipping; as "hop-by-hop" operations, these encodings are the province of the actual web server/gateway. See [Other HTTP Features](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#other-http-features) below, for more details.)

This suggests that compression should be left to the server/gateway. Which makes sense, as the server is probably much faster in doing that. Also, it might prefer [SDCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDCH) over gzip, as most modern Chrome/Chromium browsers support it.

So my question remains, should I use a middleware to compress my responses or not? Specifically, what is the right choice for [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)?

**EDIT:**

The Pylons Book also contains an [example gzip middleware](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/the-web-server-gateway-interface-wsgi.html#writing-wsgi-middleware).

I didn't mention that my framework of choice is [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/dev/) (ex-repoze.bfg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

App Engine [already does](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Responses) compress the content, if the client supports it.

> If the client sends HTTP headers with
>   the request indicating that the client
>   can accept compressed (gzipped)
>   content, App Engine compresses the
>   response data automatically and
>   attaches the appropriate response
>   headers. It uses both the
>   Accept-Encoding and User-Agent request
>   headers to determine if the client can
>   reliably receive compressed responses.
>   Custom clients can force content to be
>   compressed by specifying both
>   Accept-Encoding and User-Agent headers
>   with a value of "gzip".

Comment: Given that GAE compresses static files, does it make any sense, performance wise, to use minified javascript/css/html?